# Prestashop Webservice Add product

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I works with Prestashop 1.5 and I try to insert a product with Prestashop's Webservice API PHP, but it never works...

Is someone has an insertion script of a category, or a product ?

For example, I had found a category insertion script, but it doesn't work :

```
<?php

require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://dev.*******.com/');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', '******************************');
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$xml = $webService -> get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/categories?schema=synopsis'));

$resources = $xml -> children() -> children();
unset($resources ->id);
unset($resources ->position);
unset($resources ->date_add);
unset($resources ->date_upd);
//unset($resources ->id_parent); //if unset category will be root. If set it must have id existing parent category!
unset($resources ->level_depth);
unset($resources ->nb_products_recursive);
$resources ->id_parent = '6';
$resources ->name ->language[0][0] = 'test';
$resources ->link_rewrite->language[0][0] = 'test';
$resources ->active = 1;
$resources ->id_shop_default = 1;
$resources ->is_root_category = 0;

$opt = array('resource' => 'categories');

$opt['postXml'] = $xml -> asXML();

$xml = $webService -> add($opt);
```

I have an error 500.

Is someone has a solution ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Hi, do you turn on display_error? How to debug in Prestashop: http://blog.belvg.com/showing-php-and-sql-errors-and-debugging-a-blank-white-page-in-prestashop.html

Comment: Hi, it is solved, I've display errors, and a field was missing I think... I've forgotten what was missing exactly, but it is solved ^^
Thx anyway for reply !